# The ancient Japanese runes

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

You are Rick Perry, former Texas governor (who forgot the name of the Department Of Energy in 2012. Really?) turned archeologist. You've discovered a shrine in north Japan that's estimated to be almost 3.5 thousand years old. The shrine consists of a large tall slab of stone. Atop the stone is a vaguely humanoid statuette. Written in front of it are scratched and eroded, yet still slightly legible, runes. It's a short string, possibly a name? Underneath it is a smaller slab of stone covering an opening in the shrine. In the small hole is a tablet with more runes. Since these were protected in the hole, they're easier to make out. This was thought to be a hymn of sorts. You scrawl both texts down on a pad of paper quickly and slightly messily. Now you are back on the flight home, and are mulling over the texts. Since there have only been 4 other shrines discovered, all with similar texts, there is a basic understanding of the language, though translation will be rough and literal. You have to figure out how to translate these runes... [image: text near the statuette]

[image: possible hymn]

Hints:

> These people wanted everyone to be literate, even the blind

Comment: Nice puzzle! I knew it was braille anyway (I can read it) but the hint gives it away anyway :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is

> [POKEMON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon)

This is

> braille

If we assume 'l' (3 vertical dots) is a space we get

> Ash Ketchum
>
> I wish to be better
> No one is
> To get is very trial
> Train the won't
> I will go land
> Look long and wide
> Every ? understand
> Strength within
> *Must get
> Is you and me
> I know my fate
> *You are friendly
> On world to protect
> *Must get
> Heart truth
> Courage pull us though
> You teach me
> I teach you
> *Must get

@Deusovi pointed out this is the

> [Pokemon theme song!](http://www.metrolyrics.com/pokemon-theme-lyrics-pokemon.html)

Also

> Pokemon are Japanese

And the ? can be replaced with

> pokemon

Comment: I think the three stacked circles are a space and a vertical bar is an l.

Comment: It's the Pokemon theme!

Comment: Well this was solved a bit too easily. You've proved your worth Rick. You're on your way to forgiveness for forgetting the name of the Department Of Energy REALLY HOW COULD YOU